# Beer at a Shalom Zachor

Tags: minhag, shabbat, sources-mekorot, provenance, liquor-beer

There is a common custom I have observed to serve beer at a [Shalom Zachor](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shalom_Zachar). This is also mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7337/440) with some speculation about the source.

What is the source for this practice?

Comment: Men liking beer, perhaps

Comment: +1 although I doubt this will get a scholarly answer. Its kinda like what's pshat in eating cheese cake on shvuos? Teretz is klal yisrael accepted the Torah, don't you think they deserve a piece of cheese cake?!

Comment: OK, here's my crazy speculation - Years ago, only schnapps was served. The men who came to the *Shalom Zachor* drank too much schnapps and arrived home in a stupor to the annoyance of their wives and kids. Thus, while the hosts still put out a BIT of schnapps for *minhag*, beer became more prominent in the past 2 decades or so, as it is far less intoxicating. It's also far cheaper than single malts! If you like this comment, great, if not, I told you it was "crazy". But, think it through, a bit longer...

Comment: @DanF beer was probably more popular hundreds of years ago than it is now. It only relatively recently became less popular.

Comment: @user6591, as that famous Mussar author Benjamin Franklin once said - Beer is proof that G-d loves us and wants us to be happy ;-)

Comment: @user6591 I'm uneducated in this to agree or argue. How do you know this to be true regarding *Shlomei Zachor" (OK, I made up the plural ;-)

Comment: I'm not discussing shalmei zachorim in particular. I'm saying until recently people drank alcoholic, or at least mixed with alcoholic drinks so they wouldn't die of waterborne diseases. Nowadays you tell someone you drink beer or wine with dinner during the week and they're ready to call child services on you. But anyway see Ramma in o'ch 325 siff 10. Beer is considered a tzorech shabbos! (in so far as relying on a certain leniency there).

Comment: @Yishai maskim. And after a couple tall ones I might've also decided to go fly a kite in a thunderstorm:)

Comment: Beer is(/was) cheaper to get a large group of men intoxicated on than wine.

Comment: @Yishai: I also grew up hearing the reason given in the answer your reference.

Answer (score 2):

This [article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4232286/jewish/Why-Chickpeas-Beer-at-a-Shalom-Zachor.htm) suggests

> Perhaps the earliest mention of beer at a shalom zachor is by Rabbi
> Yaakov Halevi Lifshitz (1838–1921) of Kaunas (Kovno), Lithuania, in
> his work Zichron Yaakov, in which he chronicles the life and history
> of Lithuanian Jewry. He describes how they would proclaim in the
> synagogue after Friday night services that “so and so” invites the
> congregation to a shalom zachor, and how at the shalom zachor they
> would serve different types of beans and beer, or a different “social
> drink” (chamar medinah).
>
> There is room to speculate that we drink beer either because it is
> made from barley, which is round (like beans), or perhaps because at
> the shalom zachor, there is a custom that lighter refreshments (as
> opposed to a full-fledged meal) are served.11 Thus, we serve beer,
> which is considered less formal than wine.

You can read the Zichron Yaakov (1:22) inside [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46626&st=&pgnum=103&hilite=).

Answer (score 1):

There is an elderly Jew with lots of knowledge of tradition that I knew a while back. He came to the Shalom Zachor of my oldest son. There he said the reason for the custom is that Chickpeas were traditionally made with lots of pepper and were very sharp. Beer was served to cut the sharpness of the chickpeas.

I can attest to the sharpness aspect as I have occasionally been served the peppery chickpeas (not the bland American stuff that is popular today) at Shalom Zachors and they are indeed spicy. He was saying that this is the way chickpeas were served more commonly.

Comment: Interesting. I understand the minhag to serve chickpeas. But why does it need a lot of pepper or any pepper? Oh, I know! Pepper is "pilpil" in Hebrew which sounds like "pilpul". I guess people are meant to be confused. So, having beer sets them straight ;-)

Comment: @DanF, I think his point was that was the way they were made. I don't think the pepper has any specific reason. Almost all chickpeas have pepper in them, that is a standard ingredient. Just much less these days.

Comment: Almost all chickpeas have pepper in them, that is a standard ingredient - ??? Raw chickpeas have no pepper, and many people soak then boil them. AFAIK, commercial canned chickpeas also have no pepper, but I'm not 100% certain. At any rate, they are not "spicy", so a lot of extra pepper is added, for whatever reason. No matter, I like beer, but at most Shlomei Zachor I have attended, they have "dishwater" beer. Sorry, Millers or Bud doesn't do it.

Comment: @DanF, it's a borderline chillul haShem to serve rented beer at a zochor. We should serve good shtuff, serving a  Bud is just not proper derech eretz!

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - "rented" beer?? Don't you mean "rendered" beer?

Comment: @DanF, are you suggesting that you eat the chickpeas raw or straight out of the can? Of course you soak and boil them. Nothing but chickpeas and water?! How uncivilized. I feel about that the way Noach feels about rented beer. BTW, you aren't meant to eat canned chickpeas straight the way they are served with a Shalom Zachor.

Comment: @DanF, you rent it at the store and return it somewhat later in a different venue (I'm trying to be somewhat circumspect, this is a site for Torah after all).

Comment: @Yishai: This answer just shifts the question to "why are chickpeas served at a sholom zochor?" Also, is there any evidence that "beer cuts sharpness"??

Comment: @Yishai: Your comment "Almost all chickpeas have pepper in them, that is a standard ingredient" begs the question and happens to be false. Most chickpeas served by traditional ashkenazic Jews will have black pepper because, judging from their recipes, that was the only spice available to them in eastern europe (in addition to sugar, salt, garlic and onions). The rest of the world has plenty of other ways of seasoning chickpeas.

Comment: @intuit The question about chickpeas [was asked here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3635/chickpeas-arbes-at-a-shalom-zachor). If you ever try those sharp chickpeas and drink some beer afterwards, you will have the experience. בדוק ומנסה.

Comment: "Most chickpeas served by traditional ashkenazic Jews will have black pepper ..." Well, yeah. I'm not aware of a non-ashkenazic tradtion to have a shalom zachor at all.

Comment: @DanF: My answer [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/60516/663) may explain the black pepper.